# open a new screen in linux, no access to perl local library

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

I added my perl local library to my shell startup script (.bashrc) and when I start a terminal in linux:

```
$ echo $PERL5LIB
/home/perl5/lib/perl5:/usr/share/vcftools/perl
```

BUT

when I open a new screen (linux)

```
$ echo $PERL5LIB
/usr/share/vcftools/perl
```

and I do not have access to my local lib!!

Does anybody know why?

Comment: what did you add in you `.bashrc`?

Comment: No access to root. I generated my own lib/ directory.

Comment: I could not find ~/.screenrc!!

Comment: add `shell -$SHELL` to your `~/.screenrc`

Comment: did you add this path in your .bashrc file?